# $\cos(\frac{x}{3})\cos(\frac{x}{9})\cos(\frac{x}{27})\dots$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: pr.probability, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, probability-distributions

It is known that
$$
\cos(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{4})\cos(\frac{x}{8})\dots = \frac{\sin x}{x} = O_{x \rightarrow \infty}(x^{-1})
$$

Is it true that
$$
f(x)  = \cos(\frac{x}{3})\cos(\frac{x}{9})\cos(\frac{x}{27})\dots = o_{x \rightarrow \infty} (1) ?
$$
If so, what is the rate of convergence?

It seems to me that $f(x)$ converges to zero, but very slowly. For example $f(1081882100) \approx 0.27$. I guess the reason is that $f(x)$ is the Fourier transform of the uniform distribution on the Cantor set $C$ supported in $[-1/2, 1/2]$, which is highly irregular. To see this, let $X \sim \mathcal U (C)$, then by the self-similarity of $C$, we have
$$
X \stackrel{(d)}{=} X/3 + Y
$$
where $Y \sim \mathcal U(\pm 1/3)$ is independent of $X$. So
$$
\mathbb E[e^{itX}] = \mathbb E[e^{itX/3}]\cos(x/3) 
$$
From which we obtain
$$
\mathbb E[e^{itX}] = \cos(\frac{x}{3})\cos(\frac{x}{9})\cos(\frac{x}{27})\dots
$$

**Update.** The answer is no by Noam Elkies. However now I want to ask the same question for
$$
f_a(x) = \prod_{n \geq 1} \cos(\frac{x}{a^k})
$$
for $a>1$ and $a \neq 2$.

Comment: you will want to ask a new question, which can then be answered and accepted; combining two questions into one is not advised.

Comment: At the beginning I had in mind the general question but only asked for $a=3$ thinking an answer for this particular case works for all $a>2$.  As it turns out the answer is simple but hard to extend to a continuous domain. It seems that the number-theoretic aspect of $a$ plays an essential role here.

Comment: I doubt this product has a closed form expression for general $a$. The closest expression I know is for $a=3$ $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4\cos^2(x/3^k)-1}{3}=\frac{\sin x}{x}$$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  If $x = 3^n \pi$ then $|f(x)| = f(\pi) \neq 0$
(numerically it's about $0.466$), and $3^n \pi$ can be arbitrarily large.

Such a construction fails for $\prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos(x/2^k)$
because if some $x/2^k$ is nearly $\pi$,
or more generally some *odd* multiple of $\pi$, then
$x/2^{k+1}$ is nearly a half-integral multiple of $\pi$
and thus has a very small cosine.

[**added later**] For $f_a(x) := \prod_{k=1}^\infty \cos(x/a^k)$
with $a > 2$, the same construction does work if $a$ is an integer
(consider $x = a^n \pi$), and more generally if $a$ is a
Pisot-Vijayaraghavan number (which need not exceed $2$,
e.g. if $a = (1+\sqrt5)/2$ then there are arbitrarily large $x$
such that $f_a(x)$ remains bounded away from zero).

Comment: I presume this means that [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1838302/87355) (the red formula) is incorrect, since that does seem to converge to zero for large $x$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker  No, because that product has a finite radius of convergence
(as it must because $\log f(x)$ is singular at odd multiples of $3\pi/2$).